# SELECT INTO statement not working in java program

Tags: java, sql, select

So I'm trying to execute a SELECT INTO statement in java like this:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("SELECT * INTO SORTING FROM MESSAGES");
```

It gives me the error message 
Statement.executeUpdate() cannot be called with a statement that returns a ResultSet.

How am I supposed to execute a SELECT INTO statement? I have tried executeQuery and that doesnt work.

Comment: Can you run that query directly against your database without using java?

Comment: What database are you using? (oracle, sql server, mysql, etc.)

Comment: > executeQuery() is for getting the data from database 

> executeUpdate() is for insert,update,delete

Comment: Im using JavaDB in Netbeans, Derby Database. I dont know if thats what you mean.

@Nin-ya so how can you do a SELECT INTO statement? It doesnt seem to work with either of those methods, but I have seen someone on the internet use executeUpdate() and it worked. LINK: http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-SELECT-INTO.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but it may just be the syntax of Derby. For instance, in Oracle and some other databases that is not how you write a `select into`.

Instead, try:

```
insert into messages select * from sorting
```

Comment: No problem, please mark as answer. Also this should be tagged with `Derby`